# Django admin won't let me delete a user in its auth admin application

Tags: python, django, pinax

This may be more of a serverfault question I'm not sure.

I have two practically identical servers - I cloned the DB from one to the other, and now when I try to delete a user in the `Admin > Auth` application Django gives the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 206, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1734, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)

ProgrammingError: relation "django_openidauth_useropenid" does not exist
```

So the issue seems to be `django_openidauth_useropenid` but what is it referencing - something missing in the DB, or an application?

My site is based on the PINAX collection apps.

Comment: Looks like your clone might not have grabbed everything.  How did you clone the database?

Comment: Just exporting the DB to a file and then mounting it - I was wondering if a syncDB might fix it - I'll try that.

Comment: But how did you export it to the file? Via "./manage.py dumpdata" or mysqldump/pgdump, or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by doing a `./manage.py syncdb`

It must have got out of date somehow.